# Recursion and binding

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to understand how to work with recursion and I'm having a little trouble.

So from what I understand, if you attempt to use a local variable, the value will reset because the recursion starts at the top of the function every time (like a= [] will reset to an empty list every time).

Is there a way to complete a recursion while maintaining values ( for example, if I added values to a list) and keeping it to the local level ( within the function)?

Comment: You pass it as an argument when you call the function, in the recursive step.

Comment: Either pass the variable in as an argument, or use a loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches that I use to handle this. Each example will produce the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The first approach uses an default argument that is empty at first, but is later used to pass an accumulator to the deeper calls.

```
def build_range(n, accumulator=None):
    accumulator = accumulator or []
    if n == 0:
        return accumulator

    accumulator.insert(0, n)
    return build_range(n-1, accumulator)

print build_range(4) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The second approach uses list concatenation to build up the list by summing smaller lists. Note that this approach isn't great with lists because you keep having to build new ones, but can be cleaner for immutable data types.

```
def build_range(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return build_range(n-1) + [n]

print build_range(4) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then, a third, non-recursive approach would be to unroll to recursion into a loop.

```
def build_range(n):
    accumulator = []
    while n:
        accumulator.insert(0, n)
        n -= 1
    return accumulator

print build_range(4) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Obviously, this is kind of a tortured, inefficient example of building a range backwards (inserts are less ideal than appends), but hopefully it gets the ideas across.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard question to answer because it's not really clear what you understand and what you don't. @JaredGoguen has made a nice attempt at showing you a variety of techniques. I wanted to add a couple to it

This implementation uses an auxiliary recursive function. It works similarly to Jared's second implementation, but because of its tail call, it could be put on a trampoline to make it stack safe. This is how I implement recursive procedures at least 90% of the time.

```
def build_range (n):
  def aux (m, acc):
    if m == n:
      return acc
    else:
      return aux(m + 1, acc + [m])
  return aux(0, [])

print(build_range(4))
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Another variation on this technique is to use a lambda as an accumulator. This is particularly useful for building an iterable in a forward direction without having to keep the pending result on the stack. Again, because of the tail call, a trivial modification could be made to utilize a trampoline and make it stack safe

```
def map (f, xs):
  def aux(xs, k):
    if not xs:
      return k([])
    else:
      return aux(xs[1:], lambda ys: k([f(xs[0])] + ys))
  return aux(xs, lambda x: x)

print(map(lambda x: x * x, [1,2,3,4]))
# [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: if you're interested in a demonstration of making recursion stack safe specifically in python, let me know and I'll add a trampoline example